# Good practices - How to allow dynamic parameters to be passed to an implementation without forcing them on the interface?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, interface, architecture

My question is not specific to security tokens but that's what my example is about.
I'm currently drafting the interface of a storage service which would look something like this :

```
public interface IStorageService
{
    string Store<T>(T object);
    T Retrieve<T>(string reference);
}
```

This interface could have multiple implementations. For example:

- A local one, just using a Dictionary as a storage
- A Cloud one, using Azure Tables

Then, my problem is the following: As the Azure implementation would need security tokens (that might change at each call), what would be a good practice to take them into account without polluting the Interface for users that don't mind about this implementation?
Any idea or existing example is welcome.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Inject those values into the constructor of the service that requires them? Not really related to security tokens, that's a plain design question

Comment: That would mean having to create a new instance of the service at each call and the caller should then be linked to the implementation instead of the interface. I'm looking for something more Dependency Injection friendly but I have a hard time finding similar examples in Microsoft classes or other well-known products. Although, I'm pretty sure there must be a pattern for that.

Comment: @Padrus there's no need to construct a new instance for each call if you register your implementation with the DI framework using a factory and let it handle the injection.

Comment: You could have an overload that accepts a `StorageServiceOptions` parameter. Different implementations could have different Options subtypes specific to their needs. The one for your Azure service could have a `SecurityToken` property.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a token service that other services depend on.

It would be the responsibility of the token service to ensure that it hands out valid (non-expired) tokens, and that it performs well enough to be called every time a token is needed.  For this the token service would probably need to cache tokens and track expiration, like [AzureServiceTokenProvider](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication) already does.

eg

```
interface ITokenService
{
    Task<string> GetAccessToken(string resource);
}
class AzureTokenService : ITokenService
{
    AzureServiceTokenProvider provider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
    public async Task<string> GetAccessToken(string resource)
    {
        return await provider.GetAccessTokenAsync(resource);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, great to hear this. It's exactly how I implemented this particular concern in an application recently.

Answer (score 0):

The `IStorageService` interface only specifies how the public storage and retrieval methods are declared. Each implementation can have its own constructor that takes relevant parameters.

If the token used to connect to Azure can change with each call then it should probably be part of the method signature, and you might need to break your solution out into `ILocalStorageService` and `ICloudStorageService` interfaces.

Having a storage service where the authentication token can change with each call seems strange, as if to indicate that the location where the objects are stored or the required permissions might change between calls. Typically the location and permissions would remain constant through the life of the service.

```
void Main()
{
    var localStorage = new LocalStorageService();
    var azureStorage = new AzureStorageService("TOKEN_VALUE");
}

public interface IStorageService
{
    string Store<T>(T obj);
    T Retrieve<T>(string reference);
}

public class LocalStorageService : IStorageService
{
    public LocalStorageService() { /* no parameters necessary */ }
    public T Retrieve<T>(string reference) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public string Store<T>(T obj) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public class AzureStorageService : IStorageService
{
    public AzureStorageService(string token) { /* connect to Azure */ }
    public T Retrieve<T>(string reference) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public string Store<T>(T obj) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```